# WebChatapp with C++ I need suggestions from the start

Tags: c++, webserver

I can't decide which way I should take so instead of trying all options I would like to get expert's or more knowlageable people's ideas since I'm a C++ newbie. (After frustration with php for years I understood C,C++ is the way to go )

Extra info: I'm only linux user for a year :)

--Here is what I want to do: Webapp that people can register and chat and be friends. Like facebookchat but no less ability than it (should be realtime all the way) (For instance: If a friend closes the browser it should be seem unavailable).

--Options I have I guess: Using boost:asio, using BSD directly, using opensource server like nginx,lighttpd with fcgi   (I din't like libev, libevent.)

--Here is main questions:

1) Is Nginx+fcgi+CPP spawning a new Cpp programme for each request (Performance would be bad)

2) Would using a ready server+FCGI make it impossible or harder the chat thing i stated above.

3) Would you choose BSD, asio or tweaking a ready server for such thing?(with a short why)

(Scability for development is main concern. I mean if it requires new implementations it should be done in future)(blaa blaa must be done)

What would you do?

Comment: If PHP frustrated you, C / C++ for a web application will make you want to die. Try something like ruby or groovy or java that has a bunch more support for web applications.

Comment: @cdeszaq: That depends on what it was about PHP that he found frustrating. He might find Ruby, groovy or Java better -- but might also find them even worse.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - True, but the relative lack of existing web frameworks for C/C++ as well as the relatively high similarity between C/C++ and Java (when compared to PHP) led to my suggestion.

Comment: @cdeszaq: Learning curve is very good with php at first right. But lateron it just have it's limits. C++ have no limit. I don't really like languages running on top of virtual environments like .net and java. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd step back a bit, and consider a few questions. First and foremost, it's not apparent from your question whether you're basically trying to set up a web site (or something on that order) that provides this service, or you want to write software that (or example) others could incorporate into their web sites.

Second, it's not entirely clear whether you're interested primarily in the client side, the server side, or both. Most of what you talk about is on the server side, but the features you talk about providing are mostly on the client side.

Third, is the question of whether you're willing to write a closed system that requires your client to work with your server, or you want to use something like [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) to provide compatibility with existing software.

To summarize: you seem to be jumping directly into nitty-gritty details of *how* to do things; before you can figure out *how* very well, you first have to decide exactly *what* you're going to do. Until those are answered, many of the "how" questions can't be -- and after they're answered, many of the "how" questions may easily disappear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. *1 I'm trying to set up a web site. No other web sites 'll incorporate any service into their websites. *2 I'm interested in server site because client site scripting is easy to figure out. *3 I am willing to write a closed system.

Comment: To set up a web site, I'd look at existing servers (e.g., the XMPP site I linked lists a number).

Comment: I must check it a litle more to find out what it's about.

Comment: I see. This is (http://example1.madebymonsieur.com/) an XMPP service I found as an example for my self. Also in the XMPP servers jingle  attracted my attention: BSD licence and implemented in Google giant.  I didn't know but probably XMPP is what i was looking for thanks. I would like to ask you have you ever used any of them or which one you would suggest me?

Comment: @EmreKanca: I've never put one into anything like production use. I've done testing with a couple, but not enough to say a whole lot about them. The Oracle IM server struck me as typically Oracle -- probably functional, but seemed clumsy. I played a little with another (OpenFire, if memory serves) that seemed rather cleaner (but keep in mind, this was minimal testing, not production use).

Answer (score 0):

I would start playing with Wt (http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) which is a framework for Web applications, or Qt (http://qt.nokia.com/products/) which offer good http and https support

Comment: Thank you paolo. The implementations in website looks cool but Wt is trying to abstract underlying technologies (HTML/XHTML, JavaScript, CSS, Ajax, WS ... , SVG/VML/Canvas).  This looks very scary to me setTitle("Hello world");. I want to ask you if you used it before. Do I have option to say <title>helloworld</title> instead of setTitle for example. I don't want to have limit by using a template.

Comment: I've used Qt to produce web server applications: the distribution includes a simple http server. Using the Qt classes it is easy to develop https directly in the web server. I've never uset Wt until now, but I'm planning to play with it in a near future since its classes are modelled after the Qt classes

Comment: Do we have any option to print any desired html source? I'm checking the sources like "http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/src/treeview-dragdrop" and find no html source. It creates everything by itself. I would like to print my low level html :). Do i miss somthing ?

Comment: Apparently you should use the class wResource, which can contain raw data that is sent to the client. See this post (http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/1/topics/5) and the class documentation (http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WResource.html)